# Android implementation for socialauth

Tags: android, contacts, socialauth

Is there any android implementation for socialauth http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/

I need to be able to import contacts from  Google, Yahoo or Hotmail in my android application.

Thanks,
- Philip

Comment: What do you mean by implementation? Usage of the SocialAuth library?

Comment: Yes, I 'm looking for how to use it on android & iPhone. You 've any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an android implementation has been released recently
http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/